# Mysql throws ReplicationManager exception in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, mysql, visual-studio, xamarin

Im pretty new to xamarin so im trying to have a basic login activity in xamarin.
I have a user class which takes the user info from mysql 
this is the code

```
string cs = @"server=IserversIp;user id=Admin;password=Admin;database=newdb;";
string userCMDSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UserID=@userID And Password = @pass";

DataTable results = new DataTable("Results");
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cs))
{
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(userCMDSQL, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
        command.Connection.Open(); //throws System.TypeInitializationException
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    results.Load(reader);
        }
    }
```

I know I know not a good idea to make a direct connection with db and need a php handler in between. but this is just a sample app that i want to test with my test database first. so i used this peace of code (which is working great in desktop version) but in xamarin when i want to open connection it throws this error

**System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.**

How can i fix this problem ? I didnt find any helpful solution to this on internet that why im posting it here.

Comment: You have mysql running on your xarmarin device?

Comment: not on emulator but the one developing the code on .

Comment: then its not going to connect to "localhost" is it

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. my bad :D

Comment: Ok @BugFinder I tried it with a remote server and its still the same.

Comment: have you configured the server to accept connections from it?

Comment: Yes it accepts connections from website it self and a wpf desktop app uses this database.

Comment: that doesnt mean your device has permission

Comment: how can i check that? i have a connection string with username which has all the privileges and the server is set to listen to all ip's

Comment: read up on mysql permissions.. however.. it may also be firewall on the device.. your machine.. it could be many things all outside scope of stackoverflow